# Compiling errors on homework

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for my class and i'm getting compiling errors and I'm not sure why. I think it has something to do with my Test method.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String test;

    public void Test(String s){
        text = s;
        }

        Test test = new Test("ABC");
        System.out.println(test);

    }
}
```

Comment: new Test("ABC") expects a parametrized constructor, as mentioned by Satya above

Comment: Your braces don't line up either.  Please fix those first, it'll cause lots of spurious errors.

Comment: and class name is Test1... is there a different class Test ?

Comment: It doesn't help that your constructor is defined inside your main function.

Comment: `Method` inside a `method`.. Its just a wow... :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please be specific while asking the question. Everyone is only guessing here about your problem. Your class name is Test1 and you are creating object of Test class that too with parameter?
And there is not trace of Test class in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test1 {

 String text;
    public Test1(){

       }
    public Test1(String s){
        this.text = s;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test = new Test1("ABC");
        System.out.println(test.text);
    }
}
```

Try this..